# Is there any possibility to get any event triggered when signout from TVProvider in apple tv setings

Tags: ios, swift, background, single-sign-on, tvos

When application in background. Then signOut from TVProvider in apple tv settings.
Is there any possibility to catch that event?
Thanks!!